# How to show Currency in Canadian dollars or US dollars based on IP address in ZenCart

Tags: php, ip-address, currency, zen-cart

I have a wordpress website with ZenCart. I jus want to show currency in Canadian dollars if User is in Canada or show the currency in US dollars if user is browsing website in USA. Is there any IP detection plugin for ZenCart to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IP-detection components from this plugin as a starting point: http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=1933 and then adapt it to set the $_SESSION['currency'] accordingly at the end of the /includes/init_includes/init_currencies.php file.